# How to achieve this full width gallery using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to do this gallery, but I don't know how.

[image: This is a final gallery]

And this is my code:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/0ouqfu10/1/

I don't know why, but the height of images is not 100% in the row.

Comment: You have 2 blocks with height 300... is 600. It can't be in the row with element of 500 height. 500 != 600

Comment: I know. The point is, that the user will import images with different sizes and i need all the images in same row with counted height.

Comment: I know, that flexgrid could be the solution, however i havent found anything on google, that could help me solving the problem.